# How to add AMP to a static website, generated using middleman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amp-html, middleman-4

I am a beginner to AMP(Accelerated Mobile Pages). I have my website built with middleman as it is already built, it contains several pages on it. I knew it is going to take much time to completely validate my whole site into AMP. I am more interested in knowing are there any other ways i can validate only partials of my site like for instance[Home page]. If so

How can i generate or test my website with the AMP[version]. I mean what would be the changes needed in the build structure. Currently my layout.erb looks like this.

[I have found this link in google for standalone approach](https://paulbakaus.com/2016/07/01/about-that-mobile-in-accelerated-mobile-pages/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<%= partial "head" %>
<body class="<%= page_classes %>">
<%= partial "header" %>
<%= yield %>
<%= partial "footer" %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your website is in html, it is easy to switch to AMP

1. Replace html tags with amp tags i.e.  with  and so on.
2. Put all the css on the same page in  tag.
3. Remove all the external JavaScript including jQuery etc.(unfortunately it's not allowed).
4. And finally, validate. Your page at https://validator.ampproject.org

Otherwise you can hire a developer and he'll do it for you.